# Detect the speed of the vehicle using MPU6050

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gyroscope, mpu6050

i have been trying to get speed of the vehicle using MPU-6050 but couldn't find my way to do it so,
in the end i am stuck here

```
def stateCondition():
while True:
    acc_x = read_raw_data(ACCEL_XOUT_H)
    acc_y = read_raw_data(ACCEL_YOUT_H)
    acc_z = read_raw_data(ACCEL_ZOUT_H)
    gyro_x = read_raw_data(GYRO_XOUT_H)
    gyro_y = read_raw_data(GYRO_YOUT_H)
    gyro_z = read_raw_data(GYRO_ZOUT_H)
    # Full scale range +/- 250 degree/C as per sensitivity scale factor
    Ax = acc_x/16384.0
    Ay = acc_y/16384.0
    Az = acc_z/16384.0
    Gx = gyro_x/131.0
    Gy = gyro_y/131.0
    Gz = gyro_z/131.0
```

can some one please write the rest of it so that it returns the speed of the vehicle in km/hr or whatever it is!!!!!

Thank you

Comment: Suggest their [developers corner](https://invensense.tdk.com/developers/).

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! We will not write your code for you. We will help you solve your problems if you have specific questions, though.

Comment: [Show us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the X input training data for {A, G}, and the Y training output in kph. Plus, this code will need at least one more input, a way of learning when the vehicle is parked. The errors accumulate: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_measurement_unit#Disadvantages

Answer (score 1):

An MPU6050 will provide you with information about *changes* in motion (acceleration or decelleration mostly, but also curves). It will not provide you with absolute values. That can only be achieved by integrating over time, but this requires a known start position/speed. Also, it is very inexact, particularly with cheap motion sensors such as this one.

To get the speed of a vehicle, it is much easier to use a GNSS module instead.